# Is there a better method to check if a certain notepad file has been open?

Tags: c#, winapi, process

My current work:

-working in a different thread-

```
while (true)
{
  foreach (Process myProc in Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad"))
  {
    if (myProc.MainWindowTitle.Contains("*MyTitle*"))
    {
      Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }
  }
  Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that when I run in TaskManager the memory usage at start is something like 6000 then it raises to 9000 in like 5 sec then it goes down to 6000. I guess the problem is with the `Thread.Sleep()`.

What I would like is something steady, that checks if a certain Notepad Title has open, and if it has close the application.

You can give me C++ tips too since I can do a PInvoke to call unmanaged.

Comment: That would be Windows API, not C++.

Comment: @BaliC no. I would like to kill the console application

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? What if user opens this text file in other editor than Notepad ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula Usually people just double click txt files, they don't right click then open with. If the user double click's the file I would like to stop writing to it, so that that person can read it.

Comment: @Thanatos Use an oplock. Then it'll work for all editors, not just Notepad. It also won't create false positives if somebody has a file called MyTitle that is not the one you are writing to.

Comment: Instead of killing your process to allow reading, can you just allow read-access while you write? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx